# bootstrap - navbar not closing on mobile

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, mobile

I'm using ruby on rails and bootstrap to develop my first website. The nav bar in my website is implemented using bootstrap. However, the nav bar does not close once you open it on `mobile`. If you click or tap on the 'menu' button on the top right the nav bar open, but if you tap on the button again or outside, the nav bar does not close and keeps on flickering.

Another problem related to the same code on mobile again, is that the dropdown menus don't open at all. I think it's related to the hover functionality of the menus, but I can't seem to fix it.

Here's my code.

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" id="navbar_id" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> <!-- START OF NAVIGATION BAR -->
    <div class="container"><!-- START OF CONTAINER -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <%= link_to image_tag("logo.png", class: "img-responsive"), root_path, class:"name" %>
        </div>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="navbar_menus">
              <li><%= link_to "Item1", sample_path%></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Item2", sample_path%></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Item3", sample_path %></li>

              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Programs<b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><%= link_to "Item1", sample_path%></li>
                  <li><%= link_to "Item2", sample_path%></li>
                  <li><%= link_to "Item3", sample_path%></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                  <li><%= link_to "Item1", sample_path%></li>
                </ul>
              </li>

              <li><%= link_to "Contact Us", sample_path %></li>

            </ul>
    </div><!-- END OF CONTAINER -->
</nav><!-- END OF NAVIGATION BAR -->
```

CSS:

```
#navbar_menus{
    padding: 3.6em 0 0 1em;
}

@media (min-width: 979px) {
  ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you add bootstrap.js as a script source to your files? It's required with jQuery as well, otherwise none of bootstrap " animated" elements will work. Here you'll find it explained on [Bootstrap Official documentation] ( http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)

Comment: I used the CDN to link to the bootstrap files.

Comment: Sorry... I'm afraid I'm kinda out of the loop ... What's CDN?

Comment: @VirtuaCreative https://www.bootstrapcdn.com/

Comment: Hmmm all right.. I'm not familiar with this customized version but I believe you will need the JavaScript source (given by the link you sent me) and if it isn't enough you probably will need a script source to jQuery, before the CDN script, as the original bootstrap JS requires it.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are not closing the div:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
```

That might be causing some of the issues.